# Dynamic order by in Ranking function

Tags: sql, dynamic, ranking

I need to populate rank number with dynamically. ie i will pass the column name in to procedure as parameter and need to give this parameter in Ranking function. I write a query but that not working. Is any way, but with out dynamic query and case i need. Query Sample is below

```
DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(500) = 'name'
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @SortColumn) AS ID, EmpName, Salary
FROM Employee
```

Comment: You need either dynamic SQL or a massive `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/dynamic-sorting/) by Jeremiah Peschka. Basically, you can use a `CASE` statement to make it work. Here's a possibility:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY CASE @SortOrder
            WHEN 'EmpName' THEN EmpName
            WHEN 'Salary' THEN Salary
            ELSE EmpId
        END DESC) AS rn,
        EmpId,
        EmpName,
        Salary
    FROM Employee
) AS x
ORDER BY rn ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is the most obvious option here - you construct a string literal, concatenate your parameter, and execute the whole thing.  There are plenty of articles on the web that can help you, but the basic syntax would be:

```
DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(500) = 'name' 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SortColumn + ') AS ID, EmpName, Salary FROM Employee'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Before going that route, though, you need to do some reading on the pros and cons of Dynamic SQL - this might be heavy reading, but [you need to understand it.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

If you know of a certain, limited number of columns, you could write the following:

```
DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(500) = 'name' 

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortColumn = 'name' THEN Name
        WHEN @SortColumn = 'bla' THEN Bla
        --- ... etc.
        ELSE 1
    END

        ) AS ID, EmpName, Salary FROM Employee
```

I would recommend this second option, personally, as Dynamic SQL can very quickly get away from you and it opens you up to nasty things like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Due to SQL injection i have not using dynamic query. But some time there will be more than 15 columns will come at that time when we use case it will long. One thing i need to ask that, if there more than 10 columns then which will better is it CASE or Dynamic query ? and which will be more fast ?

Comment: Performance-wise, I think that the dynamic SQL will be faster - but ultimately, it's up to you.  Coding either way involves some extra work, but you'll have to compare performance between the two methodologies.  One advantage of the CASE statement is that you're guaranteed to get a real result out of it, not subject to typos or any other.  Ultimately, only you can decide between the two options after testing them both out.